# If not intelligent design, what is an alternative scientific theory to evolution?

Tags: evolution, philosophy-of-science

In the popular culture, Intelligent Design is often portrayed as trying to be an alternate theory to evolution.  However, as the following question points out, it is not scientific, and so cannot be an alternative theory.

[What is the viability of Intelligent Design as a supplement to chemical abiogenesis and Darwinian Evolution?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9085/what-is-the-viability-of-intelligent-design-as-a-supplement-to-chemical-abiogene)

But, this also puts evolution in a tight spot.  Science progresses by competing theories.  Yet, there is no competing theory to evolution as a whole, only variations within the theory (e.g. Neo-Darwinism vs Punctuated Equilibrium).  So, if there are no scientific alternatives to evolution, does that make it unscientific as well?  If there are no proposed alternatives, how do we know evolution got it right?  And finally, what would a non-ID alternative to evolution look like?

Full disclosure: I am quite interested in ID, and do believe it is scientific and testable, but that is not what I am addressing with this question.

UPDATE: For those downvoting this question, how do you suggest I improve it?  Is it not a valid question?

To use an evolutionary analogy, without a diversity of theories our understanding of where we came from will not evolve and remain fit.  Shouldn't evolutionary theory apply to evolutionary theory itself?

Comment: *I am quite interested in ID, and do believe it is scientific and testable* : How do you propose to test it ?

Comment: That's material for another question.  Does it interest you?

Comment: No. It doesn't interest me- I think it is a deliberate neo-creationist approach. With a premise that is based on religious belief, no test can be unbiased. 

Why downvote: Evolution is an active field of research. You should read about it (not necessarily too deeply) and understand its principles before proposing a new theory or to test the validity of a theory that lacks a scientific premise.

Comment: *Shouldn't evolutionary theory apply to evolutionary theory itself?*: Hmm.. That's what research is :)

Comment: There have been alternatives, but they're all silly and ridiculous and were quickly debunked.

Answer (score 10):

Too long for a comment: You have a misconception about scientific theories: They are not competing what is wrong or right. They are set up, tested, corrected if necessary or discarded if they can not be proven. Science (or more Scientists) has no problem with rejecting a theory when no other is available. There are always things which can not be explained with the current knowledge, but this is the way this process works. And scientists have no problems admitting this.

BTW: It is not theoretical because it is called a theory. Darwin's theory has been proven quite a number of times and works pretty well - but it has its limitations because of findings he couldn't know of, but this doesn't make it wrong. It is a bit like Newton's theory of gravity and Einstein's general theory of relativity. The first cannot explain certain phenomena that the later can, which doesn't make Newton wrong.

The other thing is, that ID is in fact no scientific theory. A theory makes a prediction, has some foundation on earlier work and can be falsified/proven. It will be corrected if it has minor loopholes and discarded if completely incorrect (For example, see Lamarck's theory of evolution, that was once discarded but is being revisited in the light of the recently discovered phenomenon of transgenerational epigenetic inheritance). 
ID is built just on beliefs and is nothing but a refined form of creationism; it doesn't make predictions and can not be falsified or tested (because it is just a *belief*). This makes it completely unscientific.

Comment: Well, if we don't have any alternatives, how do we know we have the right theory?  For example, see Popper: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjectures_and_Refutations  All other fields of science would be nowhere without being put up against alternative theories and refuting them.

Comment: Again, you have a misconception that hypotheses need to be tested in a competitive fashion. There *were* alternatives to Darwin's evolution, see Lamarckism. The reason evolution has lasted so long, and was promoted from hypothesis to theory, is because it works extraordinarily well in many circumstances. For the aspects that Darwin could not have known about (e.g., epigenetics), the theory has been improved, or "upgraded", to account for the current body of evidence.

Comment: Darwinism and Lamarckism are both different evolutionary mechanisms.

Comment: Additionally, even in the case you mention it is debatable that Darwinism has completely won out over Lamarckism.  For example, see the Baldwin effect.

Comment: @yters. there is no war between Darwinists and Lamarckists and there are no fanatic groups that support either of these so called *factions*. Darwin's theory fits in almost all situations. The neo-Lamarckists are just evoking the term Lamarckism to generate some melodrama. Lamarck himself was not aware of transgenerational epigenetic inheritance. Darwin's theory was more complete than Lamarck's, when they were published. What we, as scientists, are trying to proceed towards is a more comprehensive and complete evolutionary theory- that will explain everything. ID is just a hindrance to this.

Comment: @yters A theory is not proven right but competition. It is proven more right when the theory is able to make prediction that matches reality. If the prediction of the theory does not match reality, the theory is wrong, it is either revised or discarded. It does not matter if there is competition. If two theories failed to predict reality, both theories are wrong and we have a situation where no known theory works.  There are no competitors to evolution theory, because nobody is able to create a theory that can encompass all known facts and make better predictions,

Comment: @yters there's no alternative to gravity therefore gravity isn't scientific by your logic.

Comment: @Praearcturus before the theory of gravity Aristotle claimed everything sought its rightful location in the universe.  Newton's theory worked better.

Comment: @yters okey then

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternatives_to_evolution_by_natural_selection

Comment: @Praearcturus great, that's exactly what I am asking, what are the alternatives.  Your page and a bit of description about how they are alternative theories to evolution would be an acceptable answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

I try to avoid getting involved in these debates, but I feel the need to point out that if you *are* going to debate these issues you must make sure that you use terms correctly. Here is the first paragraph from the WP entry for *Evolution*:

> Evolution is the change in the inherited characteristics of biological populations over successive generations. Evolutionary processes give rise to diversity at every level of biological organisation, including species, individual organisms and molecules such as DNA and proteins.

None of this is theoretical - it is observable. In my opinion the term *Theory of Evolution* is so broad as to be meaningless.

Comment: This is a good comment but I think when someone shows up and their first act is to set up a soap box they may not be in receiving mode. +1